# Bash multiple if else condition for this case

Tags: bash

I need to check which of the condition failed.
Is there a better way of doing this? How can I refactor the code with less lines of code?
Maybe a one liner if/else condition?

```sh
flag1=0
flag2=0
flag3=0
flag4=0
success=0
FAIL=""

if (( 2==2 ))
then
flag1=1
fi

# check if anything is 0
if (( $flag1==1 ))
then
    FAIL="flag1"
elif (( $flag2==1 ))
then
    FAIL="flag2"
elif (( $flag3==1 ))
then
    FAIL="flag3"
elif (( $flag4==1 ))
then
    FAIL="flag4"
fi;

echo failed is $FAIL
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate over the names of the flags and use indirect parameter expansion to test the value of each flag. Use `break` to stop testing once a test succeeds.

```
FAIL=""

for f in flag1 flag2 flag3 flag4; do
  (( ${!f:-1} == 1 )) && FAIL=$f && break
done
```